# Cypress get length of a table dynamically

Tags: reactjs, testing, cypress

I'm trying to test the length of a react table.

In particular I would want that after a user add a new row to the table it's length would increase by one

In my code I can't extract the length value of the table and save it in the variable rowsLength so that it can be checked later, what am I doing wrong?

It seems rowsLength is an object not a number..

```
const rowsLength = cy.get(".MuiTableBody-root").find("tr").its("length");

cy.get("#addRowButton").click();//new tr inserted

cy.get(".MuiTableBody-root").find("tr").should("have.length", rowsLength + 1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a global variable quite often **will not work**, because of the asynchronous nature of a web app. The docs refer to this as doing a **backflip**.

The most reliable way to handle this is either with a closure or with an alias.

[Closures](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Closures)

> To access what each Cypress command yields you use .then().

```js
cy.get(".MuiTableBody-root").find("tr").its('length').then(intialLength => {

  // Code that uses initialLength is nested inside `.then()`

  cy.get("#addRowButton").click();
  cy.get(".MuiTableBody-root").find("tr").should("have.length", intialLength + 1);

})
```

[Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Aliases)

Allows you to separate the code that creates the variable from the code that uses it.

```js
cy.get(".MuiTableBody-root").find("tr").its('length').as('intialLength');

cy.get("#addRowButton").click();

// other test code

cy.get('@intialLength').then(intialLength => {
  cy.get(".MuiTableBody-root").find("tr").should("have.length", intialLength + 1);
})
```

---

**Why not a global variable?**

Using a global variable is anti-pattern because it often creates a race condition between the test code and the queued commands.

By luck, your example will work most times because `cy.get("#addRowButton").click()` is a slow operation.

But if you want to test that the row count has not changed, then using a global variable will fail.

Try this

```js
var intialLength = 0;
cy.get('table').find("tr").then((tr) => {
  intialLength = tr.length;
})

// Test that row count remains the same
cy.get('table').find("tr").should("have.length", intialLength);  
// fails because it runs before the variable is set
```

This is because the test code runs much faster than the `.get()` and `.find()` commands, which must access the DOM.

Although the above example is trivial, remember that web apps are inherently asynchronous and backflip tests can easily fail.

Answer (score 0):

With `find()` you can do something like:

```
var tableLen = 0;
cy.get(".MuiTableBody-root").find("tr").then((tr) => {
    tableLen = tr.length,
})
```

and then:

```
cy.get("#addRowButton").click(); //new tr inserted
cy.get(".MuiTableBody-root").find("tr").should("have.length", tableLen + 1);
```